# Regex validation space in the middle of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for an expression that requires a space in a string, it doesn't have to be dead in the middle just not at the end (or start).

I've had a look on google and stack-overflow, there are quite a few but I haven't found one that does what I need.

Here's what I have at the moment

```
 var re = /^[A-Z]\'?[- a-zA-Z]( [a-zA-Z])*$/igm;
```

Comment: You can match blank space characters with \s

Comment: `\s` also matches other forms of space character, e.g. line breaks and tabs, which may not be desired.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the limited requirements you specified, this will do it. It requires a string to contain ONE space, anywhere but at the start or end.

```
/^[^ ]+ [^ ]+$/
```

Explanation: anchoring to the beginning of the string, allow one or more non-space characters, followed by a single space, followed by, again, one or more non-space characters, to the end of the string.

`[^ ]` is a negated character class. That is, it says "anything but the characters inside `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be: `/^[A-Z]\'?[-\sa-zA-Z](\s[a-zA-Z])*$/igm;`. According to my idea, regex doesn't recognize a `whitespace` that why I replace those with `\s`.

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).